# Access private data members from within another class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a player class. In the class I have a hand of size three, which is of type card. Card is another class. I am trying to access the private data members of hand through class, but inside the player class. This is the error I get:

```
scat.cpp: In member function ‘void player::setHand(card*)’:
scat.cpp:117:10: error: request for member ‘cardCopy’ in     
‘((player*)this)->player::hand’, which is of pointer 
type ‘card*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)hand.cardCopy(c);
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class card{
    char *suit;
    char *rank;
    int cvalue;
    char *location;

public:
    card::cardCopy(card *c);
};
class player{

card *hand;
public:
    player::setHand(card *c);
};
void card::cardCopy(card *c)
{
  strcopy(rank, (*c).rank);
  strcopy(suit, (*c).suit);
  strcopy(location, (*c).location);
  cvalue = (*c).cvalue;
}
player::player()
   {
    name = new char[20];
    hand = new card[3];
}

void player::setHand(card*c)
  {
    hand.cardCopy(c);
  }
```

I dont understand why i cant access the function cardCopy like this..hand is a card type!!!

Comment: How exactly does `hand*;` declare a "card type!!!" ? *Post **real** code.*. `card::cardCopy(card *c);` contains an extra qualification, as does `player::setHand`, `strcopy` has absolutely no declaration whatsoever, and `player::player()` isn't even in the class declaration, yet it has implementation. **Post the *real* code**. If this *is* your *actual* code, then honestly, *stop coding* and get thee to a [decent book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: card *hand; on about line 10.. @WhozCraig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since your "hand" is a pointer you have to use -> operator to access member variables and functions

```
class player{
 card *hand // member pointer of card type
}

void player::setHand(card *c)
{
  hand->cardCopy(c);
}
```

Comment: If the text in the error message:  `maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?` didn't seal the deal, maybe this answer *will*.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are several problems with your code that i can see:

- In you class declaration, you are declaring functions without
  specifying a return type.
- *hand does not have a type in its
     declaration.
- hand is a pointer, so you need to use the ->
     operator to access its members.
- hand is being initialized to an
     array of length 3 in the constructor, yet you are not specifying
     which element you are trying to access.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#define strcopy(a,b) *a=*b
using namespace std;

class card
{
private:
    char *suit;
    char *rank;
    int cvalue;
    char *location;
public:
    void cardCopy(card *c);
};

class player
{
private:
    char *name;
    card *hand;
public:
    player();
    void setHand(card *c);
};

void card::cardCopy(card *c)
{
  strcopy(rank, c->rank);
  strcopy(suit, c->suit);
  strcopy(location, c->location);
  cvalue = c->cvalue;
}

player::player()
{
    name = new char[20];
    hand = new card[3];
}

void player::setHand(card*c)
{
    hand[0].cardCopy(c);
}
```

Of course, you will also need to provide an implementation of strcopy() within this scope in order for this to work. I have provided one for convenience, but i can not be sure that my implementation will do exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: how would i access other data members other than 0? as in how would i cycle through the hand and assign card values to it?
@android927, i also have everything else correct, i retyped my code and left out somethings by mistake

Comment: Use a for loop that goes from 0 to 1 less than the number of cards in the hand. In this case: `for(int i=0;i<3;i++)`

Comment: Also, might i ask why you are using a pointer to a char[] for the name instead of an std::string?

Comment: its a project for a class and we are required to use c-style strings...hence having to write my own strcopy and such